# Trying to delete Database (MsSQL) from PHP with PDO

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, pdo

As the title might have explained, i have a php project here.
Inside i use PDO to connect to my database. At first PHP was connected to a `MySQL-Database`. But now things have changed and I use a `MsSQL-Database`.

In MySQL you can easily do the following:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydatabase;
```

How can this be achieved with a `MsSQL Database`?

I have tried to do something like this:

```
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='mydatabase')
DROP DATABASE mydatabase
```

When i do so i get the following error

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Ungültiger Spaltenname 'mydatabase'.
```

But it doesnt work. It think this is related to the fact, that a `PDO` Connection is tied to a specific database and in my case i create a connection to database called `mydatabase`.

Im thankful for every hint you can give me.

Max

Comment: Any errors? Your query looks valid to me

Comment: you are doing these in localhost, right?

Comment: No, on our company sql server.

Comment: Meanwhile i found out, that it is possible to connect via PDO without defining the database. 

    new PDOConnection('sqlsrv:Server=myhost', $dbUser, $dbPass);

But when i call 
    self::$pdoConnection->exec(''DROP DATABASE mydatabase');

I still get errors:

Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Die mydatabase-Datenbank kann nicht gelöscht werden, da sie zurzeit verwendet wird.